# Keep bootstrap 4 navbar at the top and transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

The only way I am able to keep my navbar transparent so far is by setting it to `fixed-top` like such:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <!-- more html -->
</nav>
```

As you can see [here](https://kade-landing-page.herokuapp.com/).

I wish for my navbar to be stuck at the top of my page and to be transparent at the same time. Removing `fixed-top` removed the transparency and pushes my landing page picture (and component as a whole) under the navbar (when it should overlap the picture).

How can that be achieved?

Comment: That's not really what I want, I want the navbar to **stay** on top at all times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-overlay navbar-inverse">
    <!-- more html -->
</nav>
```

Then in your CSS write this:

```
.navbar-overlay {
    margin-bottom: -104px; // Pulls the content under the navbar up by 104px which is the height of your navbar.
    z-index: 1; // Tells the browser that your navbar should be ontop of your content. This allows your links in your navbar to still work when you hover over them.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The navbar is transparent by default**

The recommended method to accomodate the fixed-top navbar is to use `padding-top:56px` on the body.

> Fixed navbars use position: fixed, meaning they’re pulled from the
>   normal flow of the DOM and may require custom CSS (e.g., padding-top
>   on the ) to prevent overlap with other elements.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement

If you only want to apply the transparency, when the background image is visible, you can conditionally apply the `position:fixed` like this: http://codeply.com/go/4ElKQpnhy3